# Command usable as breakpoint in a batch script run from an IDE

Tags: cmd

Is there an in-built command that will pause until kepyress the execution of a batch script launched from an IDE such as Textpad?

When my script is launched from Explorer, the 'pause' command I use as a breakpoint works fine. When it is launched from e.g. Textpad (as a tool), that command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Does Textpad allow you to configure the launching method?

If it has `cmd /c` then change it to `cmd /k`
though it may have `%comspec%` where you see `cmd` in the line above.

Comment: The config currently has neither visible, and if I add /K http://i.imgur.com/0q0DnmH.png , I get failure, saying: "'/K' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Thanks anyway for the suggestion.